# about sending argument into return that have function type

Tags: typescript, return-type

first of all. I'm sorry that my English is kinda bad.
I'm learning about function type and I got stuck on "function that return function"
I wrote a code for Typescript exercise. In the type part I'm confused so I just open solution. I use his "createCipher" function code. And now I don't know how to called this and what is use case of return function type.

```
type Cipher = (character: string) => string;

const cipher: Cipher = (char) => {
    if ((char >= "n" && char <= "z") || (char >= "N" && char <= "Z")) {
        return String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt(0) - 13);
    } else if ((char >= "a" && char <= "m") || (char >= "A" && char <= "M"))
        return String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt(0) + 13);
    else return char;
};

export function createCipher(cipher: Cipher) {
    return (text: string) => {
        let result = "";

        for (const character of text) {
            result += cipher(character);
        }

        return result;
    };
}
```

I wonder how to pass argument to parameter "text" here

```
export function createCipher(cipher: Cipher) {
    return (text: string) => {
        let result = "";

        for (const character of text) {
            result += cipher(character);
        }

        return result;
    };
}

//console.log(createCiher(cipher())=>("hello"))   !!  I don't know how to console.log this
```

simplify version

```
function hello() {
  return (text:string) => {
    console.log(text); 
    return ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got my answer and looks like this question is duplicate.

if you interesting. here is link [Functions that return a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629891/functions-that-return-a-function)

and for more info

[Is it good to make function in function using 'return'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176778/is-it-good-to-make-function-in-function-using-return)

really well explain

```
function hello() {
  return (text:string) => {
    console.log(text); 
    return ;
    }
}

hello()("papamama");   //output.Log : "papamama"
```

and for createCipher function

```
export function createCipher(cipher: Cipher) {
    return (text: string) => {
        let result = "";

        for (const character of text) {
            result += cipher(character);
        }

        return result;
    };
}

//console.log(createCiher(cipher)("mysteryCodeHere"))
```